# Add delimiter if String contains a character?

Tags: java, string, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to figure out how to use a loop to append the delimiter ":" before the String s is found to contain a letter A-F.

If I have s = "10584f" then I would want the output to be "10584:f"

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: What about string like `"1abc"`? Should it become `1:abc` or `1:a:b:c` or maybe something else?

Comment: input's length is fixed or not?

Comment: It should be 1:a:b:c

Comment: The input's length is not fixed, it'll rely on user input

Comment: `str = str.replaceAll("[a-fA-F]", ":$0");`

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple solution that checks if it contains letters between a to f and put `:' accordingly.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            String s = "10584f";
            String newString = "";
            for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
                if((int)s.charAt(i)>= (int)'a' &&  (int)s.charAt(i)<= (int)'f') {
                    newString = newString + ":" + s.charAt(i);
                }else {
                    newString = newString  + s.charAt(i);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(newString);
        }
```

Comment: Use a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the `ASCII` code of each character and append the delimiter before it on this condition:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "10584f";
        System.out.println(appendDelimiter(s));
    }

    private static String appendDelimiter(String s) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(char c : s.toCharArray()) {
            int charCode = (int) c;
            if((charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 70) || (charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 102))
                sb.append(":");
            sb.append(c);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
10584:f
```

Answer (score 0):

If your target string consists of digits followed by a single letter from `A-F` or `a-f`, a simple solution can be: replacement of the regex-match, `(\\d+)([A-Fa-f])`. This regex means `group(1)` consisting of digits and `group(2)` consisting of a letter from `A-F` or `a-f`. The regex can be replaced with `$1:$2` where `$1` and `$2` specify `group(1)` and `group(2)` respectively.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test strings
        String[] arr = { "10584f", "12345A", "13456b", "23456F" };
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = arr[i].replaceAll("(\\d+)([A-Fa-f])", "$1:$2");
        }

        // After replacement
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[10584:f, 12345:A, 13456:b, 23456:F]
```

However, if the string can have multiple letters followed by digits and you want each letter to be prepended with a `:`, you can iterate the string starting from the index, `1` until the last character of the string and if you come across a letter, prepend it with a `:` as done in the function, `withColonBeforeLetters` given below:

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test strings
        String[] arr = { "10584f", "12345A", "13456b", "23456F", "1abc", "123aBc" };
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = withColonBeforeLetters(arr[i]);
        }

        // After replacement
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }

    static String withColonBeforeLetters(String s) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        // Put the first letter into sb
        sb.append(s.charAt(0));

        for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char ch = s.charAt(i);
            if ((ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'F') || (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'f')) {
                sb.append(':').append(ch);
            } else {
                sb.append(ch);
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[10584:f, 12345:A, 13456:b, 23456:F, 1:a:b:c, 123:a:B:c]
```